# Dropped column still has value when recreated with Postgres table of 150M rows

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I need to set the column to `NULL`. Until now, this has worked, but for some reason, on this table which is much larger than the rest, it doesn't seem to be working:

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."WorkoutExercises" DROP COLUMN "_etl";
ALTER TABLE "public"."WorkoutExercises" ADD COLUMN "_etl" bool;
```

However

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "WorkoutExercises"
WHERE
    "_etl" = TRUE
LIMIT 1000;
```

Returns 1000 results. Why is that, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: @ypercube: `NULL` is the default `DEFAULT`, so this should not be necessary.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, I realized that, after testing. Uncommitted transaction or 2 different tables (as your answer) looks like the best explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can only be if ...

- you did not actually commit your transaction (yet) and running the second query in a different transaction.
- or you have other transactions writing to the table in the meantime
- or something is seriously broken
- or you are dealing with **two different tables**:

It's worth mentioning that your `ALTER TABLE` commands are on `"public"."WorkoutExercises"`, while your `SELECT` is on `"WorkoutExercises"`.

Can it be, there is a second table named `"WorkoutExercises"` in a different schema, and that schema shows up in your current [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) before `public` (or `public` is not in the `search_path` at all)?

To check:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schemaname, c.relname, c.relkind
FROM   pg_class c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  relname = 'WorkoutExercises';
```

And:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

Comment: Running both those commands inside Navicat probably put them in the same transaction. After running one at a time it worked.

Comment: @Garrett: *In the same transaction* wouldn't be a problem, because all effects of previous commands are visible inside the same transaction. Must have been some other mixup, like an uncommitted concurrent transaction.